# Hibernate Criteria and DetachedCriteria concate Properties or fields

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

i have a `criteria like`

```
public ArrayList<Student>getStudentsWithPicture(final Student student)
{
    final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class).add(and(prepareForSelect()));
    criteria.add(Subqueries.gt(1L,getDetached);//the students with a less added picture...
    return new ArrayList<Student>(criteria.list());    
}
```

i need the students with a less a picture in the **table Pictures** but this Database is a legacy one

they store the pictures concatening `some fields for the student entity`

**yes a quite weird**

i want something like this

`SQL`

```
select
    this_.ID as y0_,
    this_.C01 as y1_,
    this_.C02 as y2_,
    this_.C03 as y3_ 
from
    student_table this_ 
where
    (          
        and this_.C11=true
        and 1>=
        (
            select
                count(*)
            from
                PICTURE_TABLE this_ 
            where
                (
                    this_.C03='concatening'+ this_.ID+ this_.C01+this_.C02+this_.C03//the fields of the student
                )
        )       
    )
```

**this is just a understandable example the actual query is a lot worse...**

as you can see i want the students with `status='true'` and they have a less one match on the **PICTURE_TABLE** but the field `C03` from the table is created by concatening the fields of the `Student` which i have retrieve it as well...

`my detached`

```
public DetachedCriteria getWithDetachedMatchStudentWithPictures()
{
    final String concatedFields = ...........how i accomplish this??????.................
    final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pictures.class)
       .add(equals("c03",concatedFields))
       .setProjection(addProjection("id"))
       .setResultTransformer(transformer(Pictures.class));           
    return detachedCriteria;
}
```

my question is.

can i concate the fields at runtime..??  `using Criteria A.P.I`

there is some approach?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can contact multiple columns run time in hibernate.
i have concat columns in my beloved query.

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT f.fileid , f.filename,  f.filetype , f.folderpath , max(f.version) from FileBean f  GROUP BY concat(folderpath,filename,'.',filetype)");
  result = query.list();
```

Comment: i am using Criteria API... is this possible using Criteria API